# socket transaction not going through

Tags: c, sockets, http, network-protocols

i'm in the middle of writing a webserver that's having issues sending pages to a browser. It sends the first file correctly ( this file includes two css files ). but, after it sends the second file the browser stops requesting data. it always misses one of the css files that are required to complete the page.

here's some of the transactions:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)               Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

HTTP/1.1 OK 200
Server: thserver
Date: Mon Apr 15 17:29:51 2013
Content-Length: 564

Data received: GET /main.css HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
Referer: http://website.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

HTTP/1.1 OK 200
Server: thserver
Date: Mon Apr 15 17:29:51 2013
Content-Length: 386
```

If anyone also knows a good way of validating http transactions that would help too. I did look on chrome's dev tools and showed that it's waiting to receive the last file, but I never seem to get the receive the request at the server.

Also, I used telnet to simulate a browser and it worked fine. Here's what I typed:

```
GET / 
GET /index.css
GET /main.css
```

And it sent back the file each time.

The code keeps polling the socket with read(2) but keeps returning either EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK at the time that the request for the third file should have arrived.

Here's the code for the socket io:

```
const int port_number   = 80;
const int timeout       = 5000000;
const int wait_time     =   10000;

PORT_CALL {

    /* declarations here */

    read_client:

    result = read( socket[ 0 ], &header_buffer[ bytes_read ], BUFFER_SIZE - bytes_read );

    if( result < 0 ){
        if( errno & ( EWOULDBLOCK | EAGAIN ) ){

            if( bytes_read > 0 ){

                bytes_read = 0;
                read_timeout = 0;
                goto respond_request;
            }
            if( read_timeout < timeout ){
                read_timeout += wait_time;
                usleep( wait_time );
                goto read_client;
            }
        }
        goto exit_thread;

    } else if( result > -1 ){
        bytes_read += result;
        goto read_client;
    }
    respond_request:

    /* respond stuff start */

    /* respond stuff end */

    goto read_client;

    exit_thread:
```

Here's the code that involves creating the sockets

```
temp->socket_descriptor = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

temp->server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
temp->server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
temp->server_address.sin_port = htons( * temp->port_number );

if( bind( temp->socket_descriptor,
          ( struct sockaddr * ) &temp->server_address,
          sizeof( temp->server_address ) ) < 0 ) ..

listen( temp->socket_descriptor, 10 );

wait_for_client:

new_socket = accept( temp->socket_descriptor,
                     ( struct sockaddr * ) &client_address,
                     &address_length );
```

I know I might be asking too much. Ff anyone knows a good debugging tool that might me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate that as well. I would also consider it an answer if someone suggests a debugger tool that helped me figure the problem out.

Edit: The write and read functions are in loops now, but the problem is still occurring.

Comment: Did you use wireshark or tcpdump to verify the browser delivers three requests? If so, you need to figure out which of the three requests your server "skips". To validate transactions, you have to compare the fetched file with the source file. Also, you need to validate that the response headers are what you expect them to be.

Comment: I just downloaded tcpdump, still learning how to use it.

Comment: yes, i did see the three requests in the tcp dump. i'm still not sure why I'm not getting the data but now i know i should be getting the requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just learning how to use packet capturing for debugging, perhaps wireshark is easier to start with. It offers a GUI that makes it easy to define simple rules and to visually inspect the capture. Its a matter of taste of course, so just a suggestion.

As for the code, it is difficult to say what the problem might be, since its not nearly [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I have some advice though,

1. If you are going to check things like `if( filename )` , then `filename = NULL;` after you free it.
2. If you want to zero the buffer, memset it or loop over its whole size. The test in `for( ; header_buffer[ i ]; i++ ) header_buffer[ i ] = 0;` looks dangerous.
3. Prepare for read and write from a socket returning 0, in addition to  < 0.
4. Do your writes in a loop.

Is your read looping until it has the complete request, or just until it has more that 0 bytes? Looks like the latter and that cant be right.

**EDIT, added text below:**
The code in the example is still not very complete(where is the write fex?), so it is difficult to guess the exact problem. There are a couple of quite fatal flaws however.

1. Testing the errno should not be done like it currently is, `if( errno & ( EWOULDBLOCK | EAGAIN ) )`. On Linux you can test if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) since EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK are the same. On a system where they are different, use two tests with a || between them. The current code returns non-zero (on Linux) if errno is fex ECONNRESET.
2. Now the code technically covers read returning 0, but not as a special case. Read returning 0 means the connection is shutting down and you should not read the socket any more.

One wild guess (related to #2 above) on what might be the issue in your web server is that the client disconnects before receiving the third file and the server keeps busy-looping on the closed socket.

I suggest browsing throught [Beejs guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) or some book on systems and socket programming.

Comment: thanks for answering, I fixed the errors you mentioned and made my code a little more neater. I still haven't fixed the problem but I downloaded Wireshark and am using it now.

Comment: I rewrote the code from scratch without making the program multi-threaded or dynamically linked ( just to avoid clutter ). I also accounted for closed connections, as you said. It works now, thanks for all your help.